# How to set up a Custom Query Filter with Elementor to return posts which have custom fields of post objects (multi-values) matching set criteria?

Tags: elementor

The data structures:
Two custom post types: Models and Sets.
Each Model has a custom field of type post object which allows multiple values (limited to the Sets custom post type.)

What I need:
For all Models, I want to display a list of all associated Sets.

Using Elementor's Posts Widget, I have it at least returning a specific number of Sets objects but I'm not a developer and can't seem to find the code that's going to make this work.

What I have so far:

```
    add_action( 'elementor/query/model_set_list_filter', function( $query ) {
    // Set the custom post type to Sets 
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'sets' ] ); 

    // Limit to 30 Sets
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 30 ); 

    // Get current meta Query
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }
// ???

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

 } );
```

Like I said, I'm not a developer so I just don't know where to go from here. I can't make sense of what I need precisely to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does anything work? Did you put "model_set_list_filter" in the Custom Query of the Posts Widget? Did you set WP_DEBUG to true?

Comment: @Fleks yeah, I set the query id to  "model_set_list_filter" and it definitely works. If I change the post_type value or the number to return for posts_per_page, it'll reflect those changes properly on the model page.

Comment: Sorry, I lost the thread a bit. What's not working right now?

Comment: As it is, without having a defined meta_query, it simply returns 30 Sets which aren't necessarily related to the Model. Maybe I'll get one in the returned query, but if so, it's by chance, of course. There's no filtering of the Sets. That's the problem I need to solve.

Comment: Did you try "Advanced Post Queries"? Maybe this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXjTGSUhMps ?

Comment: That actually worked perfectly. I had looked at that before but somehow overlooked that it had exactly the functionality I needed. Thanks for posting that! Saved me.